# drawable shape causing eclipse problems

Tags: android

I have a shape defined in a drawable resource this is just  textView background with rounded edge.
It actually works just fine, but when I reference the shape :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" 
   android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#7C5B77"/>
   <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
     android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

a snippet from my layout.xml file is here:

```
<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:text="Select Random Student"
android:textSize="15sp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true" 
android:textColor="#E1E7DF"
    android:background="@drawable/round_edittext_bkg"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

eclipse throws an error, although the project builds and runs and looks fine:
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
and the Error log simply says:
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at android.graphics.Path_Delegate.native_addRoundRect(Path_Delegate.java:332)
    at android.graphics.Path.native_addRoundRect(Path.java)
    at android.graphics.Path.addRoundRect(Path.java:491)
    at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.draw(GradientDrawable.java:330)

The worst part is that I can't use Graphical layout in eclipse when this happens. I have to edit by hand and can't see the layout unless and until I fire up the app in the emulator.

Anyone else have this problem with shapes, xml and eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

issue reported here :
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18472

You can try updating view to android 2.1 update1

or use `android:radius` instead of individual radius